# Ruby: Rerunning a loop with different code if end criteria is met

Tags: ruby, loops, xpath, while-loop, selenium-webdriver

I have this program I wrote to automate a task I have at work. This is my first attempt at programming, with zero experience or training so forgive any silly mistakes. (I removed the website and my username/password)

```
require "rubygems"
require "selenium-webdriver"
require "nokogiri"
browser = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
wait = Selenium::WebDriver::Wait.new(:timeout => 15)
#loads to unassigned results page
browser.get "-----------------"
p browser.title
browser.find_element(name: "user[username]").send_keys "--------"
browser.find_element(name: "user[password]").send_keys "--------"
browser.find_element(name: "commit").click
p browser.title
browser.find_element(class_name: "status_notification").click
begin
    browser.find_element(:xpath => ".//*[@id='sub_nav_content']/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[3]/a").click
    table = wait.until {
        element = browser.find_element(id: "possible_matched")
        element if element.displayed?
    }
    if table 
        puts "Table Found"
    else 
        puts "Table Error"
    end
    #creates an 2D array containing patient name, admit date and prints to screen
    names = browser.find_elements(:xpath => ".//*[@id='possible_matched']/table/tbody/tr/td[1]")
    name_array = []
    names.each { |name| name_array << name.text}
    admits = browser.find_elements(:xpath => ".//*[@id='possible_matched']/table/tbody/tr/td[5]")
    admit_array = []
    admits.each { |date| admit_array << date.text }
    name_admit_array = name_array.zip(admit_array)
    name_admit_array.each do |name, date|
        puts "#{name}: #{date}"
    end
    #finds the location of the sub-array containing patient name and collection associated admit date
    patient_name = browser.find_element(:xpath => ".//*[@id='dialog-modal-cancel-hl7-preview']/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]").text
    collected_date = browser.find_element(:xpath => ".//*[@id='dialog-modal-cancel-hl7-preview']/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[4]").text
    mo, da, yr = collected_date.split('/').map(&:to_i)
    cd = [yr, mo, da]
    bl = name_admit_array.each_with_index.select { |(name, date), i|
        m, d, y = date.split('/').map(&:to_i)
        dt = [y, m, d]
        name.downcase == patient_name.downcase and (dt <=> cd)<0
    }.map {|x, i| i }
    # presses the button associated with the correct sub-array
    blf = name_admit_array.values_at(*bl)
    if bl.any?
        bf = blf.rindex(blf.max) + 2
        browser.find_element(:xpath => ".//*[@id='possible_matched']/table/tbody/tr[#{bf}]/td[6]/div/a").click
    else
        browser.find_element(:xpath => "html/body/div[6]/div[1]/a/span").click
    end
end while bl.any?
puts "no name :("
```

So it runs the loop until there is nothing found in the array `bl`. What I want to do is have this loop run again but with the next link on the list of links. So at the beginning of the loop it should do `browser.find_element(:xpath => ".//*[@id='sub_nav_content']/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[3]/a").click`instead of `browser.find_element(:xpath => ".//*[@id='sub_nav_content']/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[3]/a").click`. Then is should run the rest of the loop in the same way. I want it to continue to increment `tr[]` each time the loop runs into `br.any? => false`.

Answer (score 0):

you can create an array of `xpath`s, and run this code for `each` of them:

```
[
    ".//*[@id='sub_nav_content']/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[3]/a",
    ".//*[@id='sub_nav_content']/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[3]/a"
].each do |path|
    begin
        browser.find_element(:xpath => path).click
        // etc....

    end while bl.any?
end
```

I believe that more changes need to adjust your code reusable, depending on your needs

Comment: This seems like it should work but when I run like this it gets to the second entry and gives me : element is no longer attached to the DOM :(